# MV3 Serviceworker won't wake up when sent a message from the contentscript

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it an expected behaviour for a serviceworker to not respond to or wake up when a message has been sent from a content script or popup. And if so , how do I wake a service worker to perform a task. I dont require a persistent SW, I just want it to run a certain function when I sent a message from a contentscript and after completion , it can go back to sleep again until it receives another message.

**Background.js**

```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if(request.message === 'hello'){
        clearCookies();
      }
    });
```

**ContentScript**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "hello" });
```

Comment: It definitely wakes the worker so I guess you should report it on crbug.com, but you'll have to provide more info and a demo extension, because it's likely they won't be able to reproduce the problem since I couldn't either.

Comment: Its probably some thing i did wrong as I don't seem to find anyone or any question related to this issue. But for now I am avoiding using the backgroundscript to execute the function and i'm relying on the popup page to handle it and that's good enough for me  but I still want to know why it doesn't wake up. I will try to post a link with the demo extension soon. I really appreciate your response. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In 2022, there are still a many bugs with service workers in MV3. They are quite hard to debug, many developers may not even know if/why why their MV3 extension occasionally fails.

Like many other extension developer, I've been waiting for months on this issue to be resolved. Let's hope google's new default to MV3 will expedite a solution.

One fix some people used to mitigate the problem is to call the SW from a sister extension or a content script.
It helps keep the SW awake, but it's obviously not optimal.

Wanted to comment but didn't have the reputation since I rarely comment. I just really felt your pain here as this issue deserve more visibility.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1024211#c31

Comment: Thanks for the response. I though I was the only one. Lets hope this gets addressed. This is a huge pain point.

Comment: Absolutely! I'm clueless as to why such a major hole in the functionality is still there. It's been preventing a projet I work on to relaunch our shiny new MV3 version.